# Need help sorting, grouping and summing up values in a Google Sheets-import

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a file that contains three columns, country code, hs-code and price. Each of these rows are one order line; a product, where it originated and its hs-code and price.

I need to have it count how many times the various combinations of hs-codes and country codes appear, and what these counted up rows cost total, based on the price of the combined rows.I have included an image, I hope it explains what I have/what I need.

I found a function that managed to group them as wished, but nothing that includes the adding of total price across grouped rows.

Link to image showing what I have/need: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5LAy.png

Answer (score 0):

Just based on the screenshot

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(r,A1:A16&"|"&B1:B16,u,UNIQUE(r),VSTACK({"Country","HS","Count","Total price"},{SPLIT(u,"|"),COUNTIF(r,u),SUMIF(C2:C16,u)})))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, I appreciate the help. This is what it returns at the moment with that function. Any idea what might be the problem? The cell-values for price are all set to 0 and there's a | at the bottom
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4jpG.png

Comment: can you share the sheet?